# kubeadm init fails when it can't find runc

Tags: kubernetes

I installed containerd and runc to /opt and I believe that's why `kubeadm init` is failing. Here is an error I see in the kubelet systemd log.

unable to retrieve OCI runtime error (open /run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/c242a3c3dbb9b0d35489ae3f99b1cd79d12a45dcf5d4a39abcd4fd045e61dc3a/log.json: no such file or directory): exec: \"**runc**\": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown"" pod="kube-system/etcd-cp0" podUID=4b344419cbf991a1f149e60ac0841c36

How do I tell kubeadm where the runc binary is? Do I need to write a kubeadm-config.yaml file or can I generate one somehow?
Thanks in advance.

```
/opt/cni
/opt/cni/bin
/opt/cni/bin/flannel
/opt/cni/bin/tuning
/opt/cni/bin/bridge
/opt/cni/bin/static
/opt/cni/bin/ipvlan
/opt/cni/bin/bandwidth
/opt/cni/bin/host-local
/opt/cni/bin/loopback
/opt/cni/bin/vlan
/opt/cni/bin/firewall
/opt/cni/bin/ptp
/opt/cni/bin/sbr
/opt/cni/bin/macvlan
/opt/cni/bin/host-device
/opt/cni/bin/portmap
/opt/cni/bin/dhcp
/opt/sbin
/opt/sbin/runc
/opt/containerd
/opt/containerd/lib
/opt/containerd/bin
/opt/bin
/opt/bin/containerd-shim-runc-v1
/opt/bin/containerd-shim
/opt/bin/containerd-shim-runc-v2
/opt/bin/ctr
/opt/bin/containerd-stress
/opt/bin/containerd
```

Comment: I added /opt/bin and /opt/sbin to my /etc/environment file.

Comment: crictl --runtime-endpoint unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock ps -a | grep kube | grep -v pause 
finds no running containers.

Answer (score 0):

Oh. I had removed apparmor. Now that I have reinstalled apparmor I can initialize my controlplane node.